# "Symbol's value as a variable is void: defun" when reloading .emacs?

Tags: elisp, debugging, init-file

I am always editing my .emacs file, and I was just wondering if I could reload it without restarting Emacs?

**Note:** I have tried `M-x` `load-file` and choosing the .emacs file, but I get this error message:

[image: error message]

Could faulty code be causing this?  Here is my code:

```
(set-background-color "#1E1E20")
(set-foreground-color "#D9CB9E")

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d//ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)

(defun defun ()
  "Insert defun function."
  (interactive)
  (insert "(defun name () 
  \"Insert description here.\"
)")
  (backward-char 35)
)

(defun hello () 
  "Just a gretting."
  (interactive)
  (message "Hello World!")
)
```

Comment: Yes, it's faulty code in your .emacs =)

Comment: @Malabarba Thank you! I will post my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to know is that Elisp has almost no special syntax--`defun` is just an Elisp macro for defining functions. Its expansion is rather simple, as you can see from running a quick macroexpansion:

```
(defalias 'defun
  (function
   (lambda nil "Insert defun function."
     (interactive)
     (insert "(defun name () 
  \"Insert description here.\"
)")
     (backward-char 35))))
```

An important thing to note: the name of the function being defined in `defun` is just an argument to a macro. Since `defun` is a macro, it does not evaluate its arguments immediately. `defalias`, on the other hand, *is* a built-in function, so it takes a quoted version of the function name--otherwise it would try to evaluate the function name as a variable.

Elisp is incredibly flexible, so it is more than happy to re-define `defun` to be a function rather than a macro, which is what you did in your code, and for functions (unlike macros) all arguments are immediately evaluated. The error I got was slightly different than yours--I got `hello` being undefined as a variable (I'm guessing your error was caused by some sort of byte-compilation or double-evaluation). Once you understand how function evaluation works in Elisp, this makes perfect sense--the interpreter first evaluates `hello` as a variable in order to pass that value to the new function `defun`. If `hello` were defined, you would probably get a "wrong number of arguments" error instead (since your new version of `defun` takes no arguments).

The moral of the story: Elisp lets you do pretty much anything, but that doesn't mean you should. **Never** re-define built-in functions or macros unless you want debugging hell.

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

`defun` is already an elisp macro, which is similar to a function. So
doing something like `(defun defun () ..)` is redefining the function
called `defun` to do something else.
Since `defun` is used throughout Emacs (including in your `.emacs`),
redefining it is a recipe for disaster.

The problem should be fixed if you change that to anything that
doesn't override a fundamental elisp function `(defun write-defun () ..)`.

### What you actually wanted

What you are trying to do is auto-insert a template for defining a new `defun`. To achieve that you can use the [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) package.

Here is an inbuilt `yasnippet` template for inserting `defun`'s [[Source](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/master/emacs-lisp-mode/defun)]:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: defun
# key: def
# --
(defun ${1:fun} (${2:args})
  ${3:(interactive${4: "P"})}
  $0)
```

### How to use this template?

- Install `yasnippet` from Melpa
- Add `(require 'yasnippet)` and `(yas-global-mode 1)` to your `init.el`.
- Restart emacs or `load-file` your `init.el`
- Now in a buffer with `emacs-lisp-mode` major mode, type `def` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

  - Magic! You will see the `defun` template inserted for you. This is because of the `# key: def` line in the template for `defun`.
  - Now by hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> consecutively, you cursor will jump through the positions labeled `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, and finally end up at the `$0` position.

If you'd like to understand that template in more detail, I would suggest having a read of [this](http://cupfullofcode.com/snippet-expansion-with-yasnippet/) tutorial by Matthew Keeler. It was very useful for me to help get started with `yasnippet`.

Comment: *`defun` is an elisp keyword. So `(defun defun () ..` will be illegal.*  Nonsense. This works fine: `(defun defun (x) "..." (interactive "sXxx: ") (message "X: %S" x))` Then `M-x defun RET abcd RET`. `defun` itself is just a symbol.

Comment: Defun is just a macro, it can be redefined. But `(defun defun ...)` is indeed a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Malabarba: Yes, a recipe for trouble. But not "illegal".

Comment: @Drew yes, I was correcting kaushal, not you. =) I was trying to reinforce what you said.

Comment: @Drew It was good to learn that. I had incorrectly assumed the elisp `defun` to be like a `function` in C. Artur, thanks for fixing the solution.